# Can we pull out a constant of a divergent series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know that if a series converges, the following applies:

$$
\sum_{n=i}^\infty c a_n = c \sum_{n=i}^\infty a_n
$$

However, I can't seem to find any info on whether this holds for diverging series as well. The property is often mentioned together with this one, of which I know it does not apply to divergent series:

$$
\sum_{n=i}^\infty a_n + b_n= \sum_{n=i}^\infty a_n + \sum_{n=i}^\infty b_n
$$

This makes me think the first property might require the same condition, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: Well, you can pull the constant out in the sense that the series on the left converges iff the constant times the series on the right converges, so it doesn't change things. That said, as Alizter said, it's not clear what the point is.

Comment: This only makes sense if you ask a question like: if $ca_n$ diverges does $a_n$ diverge? The answer is yes and can be most easily proven by assuming that it converges and deriving a contradiction.

Comment: The reason the sum of two divergent series behaves unpredictably is that they might coincidentally cancel each other out (say, $a_n=n$, $b_n=-n$). But if you're multiplying each term of the sum by the same number, there's no way that can introduce cancelation, unless that number is zero...

Comment: If $\sum a_n$ diverges, then $\sum_{n=i}^\infty a_n$ either isn't something that exists, or it's $\infty$. It's true that $\infty = \infty$, and otherwise the statement is meaningless.

Comment: @Winther, that is indeed the reason why I'm asking this. I know of plenty other ways to show the convergence of $a_n$, but I was curious whether this simple statement would be enough.

Comment: One should try to avoid manipulating divergent series (unless you do it in a rigorous fashion using e.g. regularisation) as so many things can go wrong. Working with the partial sums $\sum_{n=1}^N$, where a constant can be taken out of the sum, and then taking the limit is a better way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\sum c a_n \to +\infty$.

That means $\forall M > 0 :\exists N > 0: n > N \implies \sum_{i=1}^n ca_n > M$

If $c > 0$, you can divide both sides of the last inequality by $c$ and you can put $M' = \frac M c$.

I'll let you do the other cases.